# How to detect and highlight similar lines in a single code file?

Tags: python, duplicates, similarity, code-duplication

Consider a `.py` file like the following:

```
def function1():
    print("Hello world!")
    print("This is 1st function.")

def function2():
    print("Hello world!")
    print("This is 2nd function.")
```

In the above example, the statement `print("Hello world!")` is similar in both functions.

How can I detect and highlight such similar lines in a single file so that I can reduce them?

I have tried the `copydetect` library, but it only detects duplicates across *multiple* files, not within a single file.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a program, that parses each line and checks the similarity for each line.
There is a lib out there called difflib, which has a SequenceMathcer

Then you could check each line of similar length with each other with something like
that.

```
if (SequenceMatcher(line1, line2).ratio() > threshold):
    print("Similar lines found")
```

the method gives you a value between 0 and 1 as a float.
I don't have a full implementation up my sleve, but I think that would be the way I would check.

To speed up the comparison and not get a complexity of O(n) = n^2, you could try to only compare lines of a similar length